# Stumped With Custom Property on User Control

Tags: asp.net, controls

I have created an ASP.NET usercontrol. When I explicity provide the value for a custom property, the value is passed to the control. However, when I try to use the value from a datasource, the value is not passed to the control.

The user control sits within a FormView. The FormView successfully displays the underlying record. I am attempting to pass to the control a value in a column from the FormView's datasource. This works

```
<asp:formview .... />
<editTemplate>
<uctrl:DateSelector ID="DateSelector1" runat="server" DateValue="5/30/2011" /><br /> 
<%#Eval("MilestoneDate")%>    
</editTemplate>
</asp:formview>
```

This does not...

```
<asp:formview .... />
<editTemplate>
<uctrl:DateSelector ID="DateSelector1" runat="server" DateValue='<%#Eval("MilestoneDate")%>' /><br /> 
<%#Eval("MilestoneDate")%>   
</editTemplate>
</asp:formview>
```

I have confirmed that MileStoneDate does have a value in it. For whatever the reason, the value is not being passed to the control, however the control does recognize a literal value.

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic 
Imports System.Data 
Imports System.Data.SqlClient 
Imports System.Web.UI 
Imports System.ComponentModel 

Partial Class content_WebUserControl 
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl 
    <Bindable(True, BindingDirection.OneWay)> 
    Public Property DateValue() As String 
        Get 
            Return _DateValue 
        End Get 
        Set(ByVal value As String) 
            _DateValue = value 
        End Set 
    End Property 
    Private _DateValue As String 
    Protected Sub Page_Load() Handles Me.Load 

        If IsDate(Me.DateValue) Then 
            Dim NewDate As DateTime = CDate(Me.DateValue) 
            LabelSelectedDateDisplay.Text = Me.DateValue 
            LabelSelectedDateDisplay_DayOfWeek.Text = NewDate.ToString("dddd") 
            TextBoxSelectedDate.Text = Me.DateValue 
        Else 
            LabelSelectedDateDisplay.Text = "" 
            LabelSelectedDateDisplay_DayOfWeek.Text = "" 
            TextBoxSelectedDate.Text = "" 
        End If 

    End Sub 


End Class
```

I was refered to the post at this URL [ASP.NET User Control : can't initialize a user control property using Eval("...")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317089/asp-net-user-control-cant-initialize-a-user-control-property-using-eval)

However, based on my understanding of the post, what I have should be working.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use ViewState to persists DateValue between page requests.

```
Public Property DateValue() As String 
   Get 
        IF IsNothing(ViewState("datevalue") Then
           return String.Empty
        End If
        return ViewState("datevalue").ToString()
   End Get 
   Set(ByVal value As String) 
       ViewState("datevalue")=value
   End Set 
End Property
```

Or store value directly to the controls:

```
 Public Property DateValue() As String 
    Get 
          Return LabelSelectedDateDisplay.Text
    End Get 
    Set(ByVal value As String) 
      If IsDate(value) Then 
            Dim NewDate As DateTime = CDate(value) 
            LabelSelectedDateDisplay.Text = NewDate 
            LabelSelectedDateDisplay_DayOfWeek.Text = NewDate.ToString("dddd") 
            TextBoxSelectedDate.Text = NewDate 
        Else 
            LabelSelectedDateDisplay.Text = "" 
            LabelSelectedDateDisplay_DayOfWeek.Text = "" 
            TextBoxSelectedDate.Text = "" 
        End If          
    End Set 
End Property
```

Comment: I don't think your first statement is true, isn't ViewState enabled by default for custom controls and their properties?  The second solution would work I think, as the UserControl's members' properties will be set whenever the property is set through the binding expression (at formview binding time), but I'm not sure if this is a common code pattern.  It feels a little weird to me.

Comment: @pseudocoder - This web-user control and you must have to set value into ViewState explicitly for custom properties. On each request DateValue property is examined in Page_Load of OP code. Important  point is, the Page_Load event is called before DateValue assignment and that is the reason I've suggest second method.

Comment: Naming the sub "Page_Load()" is a misnomer since technically it is a user control that's being loaded. I'll be changing that for clarity. The control doesn't actually act on the value per se. It is a collection of controls combined together to minimize the effort needed to capture a date (in this version).

Comment: @AVD Thanks for the info.  I tested this and you are correct, you must manually persist custom properties on UserControls.  But in this case OP is not looking to persist values since the binding expression will set that property on every postback.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that databinding doesn't occur on your formview until after Page.Load, and you are checking the value of the property during that time.  If you want the value to be set in Page.Load you need to manually bind using `FormView.Databind()`.

Alternatively, you can change the code you listed in your custom control from handling Page.Load to handle Page.Prerender, if nothing requires that code to execute earlier.

Comment: @David C. Holley You're welcome!  Please remember to accept my answer if you feel it has answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the issue might be timing/event related.

When you set a property with `<%# %>`, the value is assigned to the property during the Control's databinding event. If you look for it at `Page_Load()` time, it won't be there yet.

If you change your code to check the value in the `PreRender` event, it should be there.

Comment: I think this is substantially the same as my answer, so I agree!