# Bind Property of ASP.NET User Control to One of the Parent Control's Fields

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, controls

If I need access to the value of a user control's property BEFORE PreRender, would I need to base the custom control off of one of the preexisting data controls (repeater, listview, etc.)?

One of my user controls features a gridview control that is configured based on the user control's properties on which it resides. Several of the key properties alter the SQL Statement for the underlying recordsource. I'm now in a situation where the property that sets the WHERE statement for the SQL Statement needs to tied to a value in the user control's parent FormView. Think of the formview as displaying a customer detail record. The user control takes the customer's account number and then displays data from a related table such as Customer Contact Names. Since the gridview is created before the control's prerender event, working within the prerender event doesn't seem efficient.

See this question as a reference:
[Stumped With Custom Property on User Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668711/stumped-with-custom-property-on-user-control)

Comment: Are you saying that I do need to extend a control (such as a ListView, GridView, etc) in order to be able to access a value that's passed to the control from its parent control prior to the user control's prerender event? Here's the object structure that I'm working with <asp:formview ...><edit template><ctrl:MyUserControl DateValue='<%#Eval("Id")%>></edittemplate></formview>

Answer (score 0):

What I said that you can assign value to the parent control when user control binds.

TestIt.ascx - Markup

```
<%@ Control Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" 
            CodeFile="TestIt.ascx.vb" Inherits="usercontrols_TestIt" %>
<asp:Label 
         ID="lblOne"
         runat="server">
</asp:Label>
```

TestIt.ascx.vb

```
Partial Class usercontrols_TestIt
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl
    Public Property No As Integer
        Get
            Dim mno As Integer = 0
            Integer.TryParse(lblOne.Text, mno)
            Return mno
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            lblOne.Text = value.ToString()
        End Set
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Square As Integer
        Get
            Return No * No
        End Get
    End Property
    Protected Sub Page_PreRender(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender
        'Get ref. of parent control
        Dim row As FormViewRow = CType(Parent.Parent, FormViewRow)
        'Find control in parent control
        Dim sqLabel As Label = row.FindControl("Label2")
        'Assign value
        sqLabel.Text = Square.ToString()
    End Sub
End Class
```

ASPX - Markup

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="VbDefault2.aspx.vb" Inherits="usercontrols_VbDefault2" %>
<%@ Register src="TestIt.ascx" tagname="TestIt" tagprefix="uc1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True">
            <ItemTemplate>
                No :
                <uc1:TestIt ID="TestIt1" runat="server" No='<%#Eval("No") %>' 
                    ClientIDMode="AutoID" />
                <br />
                Square :
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server"    ></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:FormView>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

ASPX.vb

```
Partial Class usercontrols_VbDefault2
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Public Class TestData
        Public Property No As Integer
    End Class
    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not IsPostBack Then
            BindData()
        End If
    End Sub
    Sub BindData()
        Dim nos As New List(Of TestData)
        nos.Add(New TestData() With {.No = 10})
        nos.Add(New TestData() With {.No = 20})

        FormView1.DataSource = nos
        FormView1.DataBind()
    End Sub
    Protected Sub FormView1_PageIndexChanging(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.FormViewPageEventArgs) Handles FormView1.PageIndexChanging
        FormView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
        BindData()
    End Sub
End Class
```